# Multiple networks on a single switch, or a router?

Tags: ubuntu, router, switch

This is kind of different than usual VLAN scenarios. I'm building a robot that is composed with a few linux machines. They communicate to each other over ethernet.

The user of the robot can communicate to this robot network 3 ways:

1. Connect an ethernet cable between a laptop and the robot switch(Direct eth)
2. Connect to the AP with a laptop. The AP is hooked to the robot switch.
3. Connect facility LAN to the robot switch. Now all computers on the facility LAN can control it.

Caveats:

1. The AP cannot be removed
2. A single port is used on the switch either for direct eth or facility LAN
3. Only one network connection is needed at a time. If LAN is plugged in, ignore AP.

I looked into VLAN with a layer-2 switch, but having some trouble making it work. Is that the wrong approach? How do I accomplish this with a router?

Comment: I think you're going to need to give some more details about your setup or what you're wanting to do. For example, the way you described "LAN" and "direct ethernet" sound identical to me.

Comment: @SamForbis thanks, I've updated my post, hopefully clarifies. I essentially need to connect a LAN to 3 other LAN.

Comment: I'm assuming you have some sort of control of the facility network?

Comment: @SamForbis yea but I'd like the facility network to be plug and play in this situation. If the robot was brought to a different facility it would be a pain to reconfigure if that was the case

Comment: Does the robot only have a switch, not a router on-board?

Answer (score 0):

If your robot is set up with the Linux/Ubuntu boxes and the AP linked together on-board with a switch, as long as you manually configure IP addresses for each of them there will be no problem. For example, using the 10.0.0.0/24 network, you could assign the Ubuntu boxes and the AP any address in the 10.0.0.1-10.0.0.254 range.

This way, all you would need to do is manually set an IP address on your laptop or any other computer which you would use to connect to the robot. Connect to the AP on the robot, manually set your computer's IP address to any IP address in the range that's not already taken, and it will be able to see and communicate with the devices on the robot.

Likewise, connect your PC directly to the robot switch via Ethernet, set your IP to an unused address on that network, and you'll be able to connect. Without a router that can assign IP addresses on your robot, you will have to use static, manually-assigned IP addresses. Alternatively, you could have one of the Ubuntu machines be a DHCP server and assign IP addresses on the network.

The real issue is with the facility network. If you wish to connect your robot with an Ethernet cable to a building's LAN, you need to be somewhat aware of the LAN's network structure and, as far as I know, there is no easy way to dynamically change an entire existing network's settings to facilitate communication with another arbitrary network (especially not without a router on-board the robot) in a way like you're wanting.

However, assuming there are no special firewall rules or conflicting network addresses on the building LAN, you should be able to connect your computer (or any other computer on the LAN) to the robot. The caveat here being that the computer's IP must also be manually set to an address on the proper network (10.0.0.0/24 in my example). Hope this helps.